# CUDA out of memory error, cannot reduce batch size

Tags: python, pytorch

I want to run some experiments on my GPU device, but I get this error:

> RuntimeError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 3.63 GiB (GPU 0;
> 15.90 GiB total capacity; 13.65 GiB already allocated; 1.57 GiB free; 13.68 GiB reserved in total by PyTorch)

I read about possible solutions [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/16417), and the common solution is this:

> It is because of mini-batch of data does not fit onto GPU memory.
> Just decrease the batch size. When I set batch size = 256 for cifar10
> dataset I got the same error; Then I set the batch size = 128, it is
> solved.

But in my case, it is a research project, and I want to have specific hyper-parameters and I can not reduce anything such as batch size.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: I've encountered similar issues before in my own research.   The alternatives for me were using some equivalent of sparse tensors (if possible), or recruiting more GPUs to distributed my data across. The latter is fairly straightforward in `pytorch-lightning` if you're using `pytorch`. It's similarly straightforward  in `pytorch` if you're going framework free, though has a bit more overhead you need to write.

Comment: Is your research project that sensitive to BATCH_SIZE? Does the model not converge at smaller batch sizes?

Comment: @pavel Actually it is a study of sensitivity analysis. my models converge. But I want to compare them and see how sensitive they are with respect to these hyper-parameters

Comment: @John Thanks for your suggestions. I will try them as my second option.

Comment: Then you need another graphics card.... or train model on CPU.

Answer (score 8):

As long as a single sample can fit into GPU memory, you do not have to reduce the *effective* batch size: you can do [gradient accumulation](https://medium.com/huggingface/training-larger-batches-practical-tips-on-1-gpu-multi-gpu-distributed-setups-ec88c3e51255).
Instead of updating the weights after every iteration (based on gradients computed from a too-small mini-batch) you can *accumulate* the gradients for several mini-batches and only when seeing enough examples, only then updating the weights.
This is nicely explained [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TibQO_xv1zc&t=348s).

Effectively, your training code would look something like this.
Suppose your large batch size is `large_batch`, but can only fit `small_batch` into GPU memory, such that `large_batch = small_batch * k`.
Then you want to update the weights every `k` iterations:

```py
train_data = DataLoader(train_set, batch_size=small_batch, ...)

opt.zero_grad()  # this signifies the start of a large_batch
for i, (x, y) in train_data:
  pred = model(x)
  loss = criterion(pred, y)
  loss.backward()  # gradeints computed for small_batch
  if (i+1) % k == 0 or (i+1) == len(train_data):
    opt.step()  # update the weights only after accumulating k small batches
    opt.zero_grad()  # reset gradients for accumulation for the next large_batch
```

Comment: Shouldn't the loop be on `enumerate(train_data)`?

Comment: Also, I doesn't the loss need to be divided by `k`?

Answer (score 7):

Shai's answer is suitable, but I want to offer another solution. Recently, I've been observing awesome results from Nvidia AMP - Automatic Mixed Precision, which is a nice combination of the advantages of fp16 vs fp32. A positive side effect is that it significantly speeds up training as well.

It's only a single line of code in tensorflow: `opt = tf.train.experimental.enable_mixed_precision_graph_rewrite(opt)`

More details [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/automatic-mixed-precision)

You can also stack AMP with Shai's solution.

Comment: AMP is great. You can also have it for pytorch, see [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/amp.html) note that you should use `amp` with gradient scaling.

Comment: Would AMP also help in CUDA out of memory problem? I think it'll just enable mixed precision OR is it that by reducing the precision to fp16, we're not occupying a lot of memory?

Comment: fp16 uses half the memory of fp32. With mixed precision, I usually see a 20-40% decrease in memory usage, sometimes a bit more.